# Outlook 2010 - strange item.Attachments error

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have the following code, that should save a specific Excel file attached to an email. The code is combined with a rule, that trigger this script when an emai lwith a specific subject is received.

The code is triggered, but here comes the strangest error I saw lately: itm.Attachments.Count appear  to be zero and obviously the file is not saved! But... if I put a breakpoint on "For each..." line and add itm.Attachments.Count to watch window, it is shown as zero. If I add itm only, then browse to Attachments property, then to Count property it shows 1 for Count (as it should) and the code is executed fine. I spent half a day trying to understand what's going on, but I can't figure it out.

The behaviour is the same both on a Outlook 2010 x64 on a Windows 7 x64 and on a Outlook 2010 x86 on a Windows 7 x86. Macros are enabled in Trust Center. I have attached some screenshot with the code and rule settings and also a movie showing the watch windows strangeness.

The script was built some time ago and it worked well on a couple of PCs and it was based on the steps from here: iterrors.com/outlook-automatically-save-an-outlook-attachment-to-disk/.
Any ideas?

[**Rule screen here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-aVIPSg4hsRFgxdzFtd3l1SkE/view?usp=sharing)
[**1 min. movie here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-aVIPSg4hsZERQWUJHLXd4bjA/view?usp=sharing)

```
Public Sub Kona(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\test"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Kona Preferred Fixed Price Matrix (ALL)") Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of store is this? IMAP4?

Comment: If it is an Exchange account, go to File > Account Setting > open your Exchange account > Adjust "Mail to keep online" to "All", restart Outlook to check the result.

Comment: It is a gmail account, added as IMAP in Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have an IMAP account configured in Outlook: your Offline Settings might be set to only store up to 1 month, 3 months, 12 month worth of emails on your local disk.

If you’ve got enough space on your disk and want to cache more emails locally, you can set the sync slider in the following way:
File-> Account Settings-> Account Settings…-> double click on your IMAP account.

Try to increase the offline storage in Outlook. See [Empty Inbox and other IMAP synching issues in Outlook 2013](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/840) for more information.

Comment: I can't find that slider in Outlook 2010

Answer (score 1):

My best understanding of this behavior is that Microsoft Outlook (at least the versions of 2010 that I tested) has a bug. There may be other factors that I'm not aware of contributing to this, but I was able to reproduce the error using different service pack levels / builds of Outlook 2010 on Windows Vista. Office 2013 does not appear to be affected.

I managed to create a workaround.

I found that by displaying the message while stepping through the code in debug mode using

```
objMailItem.GetInspector.Activate
```

the number of attachments was subsequently correctly detected (without having to do strange things like setting up a watch for the object variable and then clicking on it in the IDE).

However, this only worked while stepping through the code, not during normal execution.

For this reason, I suspected the message might not be displaying long enough during normal code execution for Outlook to get the twist out of its knickers. I reasoned that it might be possible to insert a delay to allow sufficient time for this.

I tried out several methods of inserting a delay. Here is the one that worked for me. I created a form called

```
frmTimer
```

and added the freeware RSTimer OCX control (http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/RS-Timer.shtml) to it.

I set the

```
Interval
```

property of the OCX to 1000 ms.

The form is loaded right after displaying the message like this:

```
objMailItem.GetInspector.Activate
frmTimer.Show ' <-- form is loaded and displayed (it is not sufficient to just 'load' it)
objMailItem.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard
```

The form has one single event handler:

```
Private Sub RSTimer1_Timer()

    Unload frmTimer

End Sub
```

When the event fires, the form is unloaded and code execution continues with

```
objMailItem.GetInspector.Activate
frmTimer.Show
objMailItem.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard ' <-- code execution continues here
```

Here is a complete function that allows the attachment to be detected correctly.

```
Function EmailHasAttachments(ByVal objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    objMailItem.GetInspector.Activate

    frmTimer.Show

    objMailItem.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard

    If objMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        EmailHasAttachments = True
    Else
        EmailHasAttachments = False
    End If

ExitHere:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 12345
        ' handle the error
    Case Else
        MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred."
        Exit Function
    End Select

End Function
```